# Android Gallery Import

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery

I am using gallery picker for picking an image from gallery. The photos taken by the camera in portrait mode is shown in the gallery as straight. But when I import the photos, i get the photo as rotated (landscape). Only gallery is showing this picture as straight. How to manage this problem?  I want all photos as its actual orientation.
Thanks in advance

```
private void addImageFromGallery() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
            GALLERY_CODE);

}
```

Comment: Gallery knows the exact orientation of the phone while taking the picture. So it rotates the picture. But I am not getting that.

Comment: **[This Tutorial Can Help you](http://startandroiddevelopment.blogspot.in/2013/10/importing-image-from-gallery.html)**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got the answer. The orientation is saved with the image in EXIF format. We have to read the Orientation tag of the data for each image..

```
public static float rotationForImage(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
        String[] projection = { Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION };
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            return c.getInt(0);
        }
    } else if (uri.getScheme().equals("file")) {
        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(uri.getPath());
            int rotation = (int)exifOrientationToDegrees(
                    exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL));
            return rotation;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error checking exif", e);
        }
    }
        return 0f;
    }

    private static float exifOrientationToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {
    if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
        return 90;
    } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
        return 180;
    } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
        return 270;
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

The rotation value can be used to correct a photo’s orientation as follows:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
float rotation = PhotoTaker.rotationForImage(context, uri);
if (rotation != 0f) {
      matrix.preRotate(rotation);
 }

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
 sourceBitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
```

Comment: Work great... Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

Comment: Why does rotationForImage return a float? Wouldn't an int suffice?

Answer (score 0):

while setting it to the imageview, check if the width of the image is greater than height or not and rotate it to 90 if needed

Comment: That is not possible because we are getting all image in the ratio 640X480.

Comment: Got the answer... An orientation tag is saved with each image. Check this link http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/08/rotating-images-in-android/

Comment: post your answer. It will be useful to others